# file system not supported error while adding a file to sql filegroup with filestream

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, filestream, filegroup

hi i am a beginner with sql server 2008, i was trying to add a file to a filegroup so that i an create a table which uses filestream, but i keep getting an errors.

here is the code that i am trying:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbtry1

ADD FILEGROUP dbtry1_fg_filestream CONTAINS FILESTREAM

GO

ALTER DATABASE dbtry1

ADD FILE

(

NAME= 'dbtry1_filestream',

FILENAME = 'E:\Projects\fs.ndf'

)

TO FILEGROUP dbtry1_fg_filestream

GO
```

the errors:

Msg 5134, Level 16, State 2, Line 1

The path that is specified by 'E:\Projects\fs.ndf' cannot be used for FILESTREAM files because it is not on a supported file system.

Msg 5009, Level 16, State 14, Line 1

One or more files listed in the statement could not be found or could not be initialized.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

> it is not on a supported file system.

- Is it local NTFS?
- Compressed and not using 4k clusters?

[More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd206979.aspx)

Edit:

After comment.. no, you can't use FAT 32. Why do you still have this? You are limited to 4GB file size and I'm sure FILESTREAM would hit this quickly.

Comment: FAT32? Last thing I saw that used that by default was Windows ME...or a USB flash drive.